# I am creating a alert box in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build a alert box in android studio, i have 2 xml and 1 activity class where on click of a button i want to show the other layout.
I am getting a error, here is my code of MainActivity

```
 cancelBookingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_cancel_confirm, null);
            final TextView disAgree = (TextView) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.TextDisagree);
            final TextView Agree = (TextView) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.TextAgree);


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Current Booking");
            // This will set the view from XML inside ALertDialog
            alert.setView(alertLayout);
            // disabling cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch

            alert.setCancelable(false);

            AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

In this line i am getting error

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

> In Builder cannot be applied
>   Any idea why i am getting this.

Comment: Try `new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);` where `MainActivity` is the class name of the activity in which this code is in.

Comment: @Firdoeshkhan you can achieve this by custom dialog too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Current Booking");
            // This will set the view from XML inside ALertDialog
            alert.setView(alertLayout);
            // disabling cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch

            alert.setCancelable(false);

            AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();
```